# Python. Requests. Post. Usual ways to log in don't work

Tags: python, logging, request, response, http-status-code-403

Try to log in in this site "websim.worldquantchallenge.com/login", but usual ways don't work. In most cases and websites we can use next form:

```
session = requests.session()
url = 'https://websim.worldquantchallenge.com/login'
data = {
    'EmailAddress': '<YOUR_MAIL>', 
    'Password': '<YOUR_PASS'
}
result = session.post(url, data = data)
print(result)
```

But in this situation I get "response 403".

Simle ways of Authentication as "HTTPBasicAuth" or "HTTPDigestAuth" also do not work. So how can I log in in this case?

Comment: perhaps the website doesn't want you logging in via code?

Comment: What is the request sent when you login through the UI ?

Comment: Have you tried opening a browser's developer console, switching to the network view, and watching the actual login sequence for that site? It may surprise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **you have to make sure that the website's policy allows login via code**.

If so, the url of the post should be:

```
url = 'https://websim.worldquantchallenge.com/login/process'
```

Comment: And sorry again, but could you explain me how did you know that it could help? =)

Comment: I tried to observe from the Chrome's network view what was the address of the POST sent from the form page!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the form is handled by javascript, so you don't really know what url the data is going to. For issues with websites where request doesn't seem to work, I've used selenium. It uses the chrome driver to pull up the page in the browser. You then find the element by class or id and fill in the form and click submit.

A lot of websites are moving to this javascript interaction style to prevent automated code from scrapping their site. I also see code for captcha so you might have to deal with that if that presents itself.

Comment: Yea, I use selenium now, but want to speed up my working

Comment: A mix between requests and selenium after logging in works too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest logging in through the website with developer tools activated and looking at the request/response content.
Some possible reasons for not being able to log in using your usual method:

- the form changed (e.g. 'EmailAddress' replaced by 'Username', a new field in the form)
- the authentication method changed (e.g. new url, OAuth2...)
- the website is preventing programmatic access by filtering on user-agent or adding hidden fields in the login form

And, a basic question: have you looked at the error message you're getting with the 403 (`print(result.text)`) ?

Comment: When i had got response 405, i looked at result.text, and didnt get any information. 
Now i tried to do it and understood what you mean, although other user helped me with this problem ) 
Thanks.